# Drools : finding the facts which satisfy the criteria

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner

I'm beginner to Drools, I need some help in how to structure the rules.

```
class Question{
   private Difficulty difficulty;
   private Type type;
   private int marks;
   //getter and setters method
}

enum Difficulty{
     HARD,EASY,MEDIUM
}

enum Type { SUBJECTIVE,OBJECTIVE}
```

Description: I have a Question class which has a Difficulty and Type as enum. As a part of request I get  a1% of EASY questions , a2% of HARD questions, a3% of MEDIUM questions , b1% of Subjective Questions ,b2% of Objective Questions and total marks of all the questions.

How Do i proceed in writing the rules so that i have set of questions which in total has the described % of EASY,HARD,MEDIUM,SUBJECTIVE,OBJECTIVE questions ?

Comment: Which criteria? If you get a certain set of questions with the given percentages, what is there to decide?

Comment: please have a look at edited post

Comment: I think this is a variant of the packing problem. I have added the planner tag.